# Update json Object w/ json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following class for my Json file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MITSonWald
{
    public class ExtLine
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, List<LineList>>> LineList { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineList
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, List<Device>>> DeviceList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Device
    {
        public string Volume { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Resulting Json File**

```
{
  "LineList":[
    {
      "TapiLine22":[
        {
          "DeviceList":[
            {
              "192.168.10.204":[
                {
                  "Volume":"5",
                  "Name":"Büro"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to add an object to the `DeviceList` but I can't get it done.

**What I tried**

```
/* Deserialize Json File */
dynamic json =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtLine>(
           File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg\\lines.json"));

List<Dictionary<string, List<Device>>> myDevice = new List<Dictionary<string, List<Device>>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, List<Device>>
    {
        {
            "192.168.10.205",
            new List<Device>
            {
                new Device
                {
                    Name = "Zimmer2",
                    Volume = "5"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

json.LineList[0]["TapiLine22"][0].DeviceList.Add(myDevice);
```

Thrown Exception (Google Translate from German)

```
Additional Information: The best match for the overloaded System.Collections.Generic.List <System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary <string, System.Collections.Generic.List <MITSonWald.Device >>>. Add (System.Collections.Generic. Dictionary <string, System.Collections.Generic.List <MITSonWald.Device >>) method contains some invalid arguments.
```

Comment: Yes, it's worth posting the exception - at least the exception type will be useful, and there's always Google Translate for the message. Ideally, provide a [mcve] so we can try this for ourselves... (Are you actually parsing any JSON at the moment? It sounds like you're not up to that part yet...)

Comment: Did this code compiled fine? Please post the exception as well. Shouldn't you be adding your `myDevice` to the collection first and then convert it to json instead ?

Comment: what type is `json` of?

Comment: Updated question a little and added exception. `json` is `dynamic`. The code compiles fine, exception is thrown when i call the function. Where can I post a working example online? Is there sth. like jsfiddle for .net?

Comment: I think `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtLine>` should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LineList>` right? because you are accessing the property `DeviceList` which is not declared in `ExtLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception it looks like your Add is expecting:

```
Add (Dictionary<string, List<MITSonWald.Device>>)
```

but you are adding object of type

```
List<Dictionary<string, List<Device>>>
```

This should work(but it will replace your list):

```
json.LineList[0]["TapiLine22"][0].DeviceList = myDevice;
```

because your myDevice is the same type as DeviceList.

You could also just create dictionary and add it to DeviceList(just throw unneeded list):

```
var myDevice = new Dictionary<string, List<Device>>
{
    {
        "192.168.10.205",
        new List<Device>
        {
            new Device
            {
                Name = "Zimmer2",
                Volume = "5"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `json.LineList[0]["TapiLine22"][0].DeviceList = myDevice;` works indeed but replaces the existing device. I don't understand the second part, that's exactly what I'm doing? (Which causes the exception).